# Do I need encryption for the password in this case?

Tags: c#, windows, email, smtp

A Windows Desktop C# application will periodically send email from client to myEmail@gmail.com. The password of the email(myPassword) I use is very explicit in the code as shown:

```
        SmtpClient smptp = new SmtpClient();
        smptp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smptp.Port = 587;
        smptp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        string myPassword = "123456789";
        System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("myEmail@gmail.com", myPassword);
        smptp.EnableSsl = true;
        smptp.Credentials = nc;
        smptp.Send(mm);
```

I will only share the exe file or installer with the client not the source code. Can myPassword be still hacked in that case? If so, how to encrypt it programmatically?

Comment: .net executables can be decompiled pretty easily. If you distribute an exe then expect whoever you sent it to can read every line of code within.

Comment: This is .NET. If you are shipping the application you are practically shipping its source code. Decompiling .NET code is trivially easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, someone could read the password using some disassembler (e.g. ildasm), I think there is not much to do in this scenario, the best recommendation it is not to store the password, but network credential requires a plain text string. You could try setting/getting the value in config file, then you could encrypt that config file.

Comment: ", but network credential requires a plain text string." what do you mean by that?

Comment: It means that the example you provide is correct, the credential value assignment is supposed to work that way.